# Converting a std::string to int in C++03

Tags: c++, stringstream, c++03

I am looking for a method to convert a string represent of an integer (say, "123") to an integer in C++03.

I am aware about the usual method of using `stringstreams`:

```
string token="1234";
stringstream sss(token);
int tokenInt;
sss>>tokenInt;
cout<<"Int token is: "<<tokenInt<<"\n";
```

However, the problem with this is that it doesn't appear to work on values like `1e1`.  It just prints out `1`.  Working demo [here](http://ideone.com/lRf7Bq).  `stoi` is unfortunately ruled out since I am using C++0x.  Any other way?

Thanks!

Edit:  I am basically working on IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.  The function `ipValidator()` returns valid if it is a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address.  I split the input, say, `1e1.4.5.6` into tokens `1e1`, `4`, `5` and `6`.  Since, `1e1` is incorrect, I need to return false.  Unfortunately, the above method returns `true` since it process `1e1` as just a `1`.

Comment: did you try using atoi?

Comment: Are you talking about C++03 or C++11? "C++0x" was the development name of C++11, which was originally slated to come out before 2010.

Comment: @ɯɐɹʞ, I might be wrong here, but isn't `atoi` a C++11 feature?

Comment: There is no justification for using atoi in either C or C++.

Comment: @zneak, I am sorry.  I meant C++03.  I mistakenly assumed that C++0x meant C++03.

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela Did you look at the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi)? Short answer: No, it isn't.

Comment: 1e1 is floating point, read `double` or `float` from stream and convert it to `int` with proper rounding.

Comment: @ɯɐɹʞ, using `atoi` gives this: `cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int atoi(const char*)'`.

Comment: @Slava, I am coding to validate IP address tokens (each set of strings separated by a `.`).  So, I am assured that if it is floating point, then I need to return false.  Anyway in which I could do this without using a double?  Also, due to memory limits, a `double` won't be feasible.

Comment: `token.c_str()` will give you the `const char*`, so you can wrap it in the `atio()`

Comment: Then why do you care about 1e1?  That won't be in an IPV4 IP address.

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela Once again, did you read the documentation of `atoi`? It accepts `char*`, hence to use it, with `std::string`, you would need to pass in the C-like string, you get from calling  `std::string::c_str ()`.

Comment: @NathanOliver, totally agree.  But that can be in the input (and I need to return false).  Also, IPv6 address are in scope, so cannot just check for an `e` in the string.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius, yes, but I wasn't aware about `c_str()`.  Sorry, I am still learning :)

Comment: Describe your problem properly, do you need to process 1e1? Which way?

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela If that is the case what you do is see if the stream hit the EOF.  If it did you have a valid conversion.  If not you know you got bad input.

Comment: @Slava, updated the question.  Sorry for the earlier confusion.

Comment: Use regex that would be simplest and cleanest solution

Comment: @Slava, yeah, I will learn that as well.  But for now, I wish to understand this to get a good understanding of `stringstreams`

Comment: @NathanOliver, could you please elaborate, sir?

Comment: check the result of `sss.eof()`.  If it is not true then you have a bad conversion.

Comment: @NathanOliver, awesome, that did the trick.  Please convert it into an answer and I will accept it.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.  After you do the conversion you need to check if there is any data left in the stream.  If there is then you know you had invalid input.  So if

```
the_stream.eof()
```

is `true` then you consumed on the input and you have a valid result.  If not then you have invalid input.

Comment: `strtol` can be used as well and most probably would work significantly faster

Answer (score 1):

You can use C function  `strtol` as well:

```
std::string token = "1234";
char *endp = 0;
int value = strtol( token.c_str(), &endp, 10 );
if( **endp ) { // invalid symbol detected
    ...
}
```